# How do I create a Pulse Chart/Timeline with a categorical Y-axis?

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

I feel like I am being stumped by a fairly basic problem.

I need the Y-Axis to be a categorical variable. No aggregation. The markers/dots are simply the dates of occurrence of each categorical value as plotted against the X-Axis's list of dates.

Currently, I am working in Microsoft's Pulse Chart visual, but open to whichever visual is optimal. Not sure which field to place the categorical column.